# How to search for entirely bold paragraphs?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to be able to find paragraphs that are wholly bold (such as a subheading), but I've been struggling to figure it out or find much help online. I've seen similar questions but the responses are too complicated for me to really know what I'm replicating, despite trying to use parts that seem relevant.

My end goal is to, after finding a wholly bold paragraph, delete the character immediately following it (usually an empty line).

So far, this is my code, using MsgBox as my quick easy test to see if the search works correctly:

```
Dim para As Paragraph

For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If Selection.Font.Bond = True Then MsgBox "All Bold"
    Else: Next para
```

What this macro does is bring up a MsgBox saying "All Bold" for each paragraph in the document (as in, if there are 50 paragraphs it brings the MsgBox up 50 times), rather than check each paragraph then bring up a MsgBox IF it's entirely bold. Ideally, in my actual document of about 50 paragraphs, only the 3 headings would prompt the MsgBox to appear.

Comment: you are iterating all Paragraphs in para variable but in a loop you are not using para

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code doesn't select anything `Selection.Font.Bold` does not relate to anything in the loop. By simply changing `Selection` to `para.Range` you will find only those paragraphs you are looking for.

```
Dim para As Paragraph

For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If para.Range.Font.Bold = True Then para.Next.Range.Delete
Next para
```

The paragraph following can be accessed simply by using the Next property.

If the headings have been formatted using a style you could find them simply by looking for all instances of that style.

Comment: Unfortunately they have not, and it would require the same kind of macro in order to search for said paragraphs to apply a style. It takes extracted text, rather than text I've originated.

Comment: @CatJ if this has solved your issue please mark the answer as accepted. Doing so can help others who may have the same problem.

Comment: I've changed the MsgBox bit to MoveRight once and Delete once, but it's still doing that based on the number of bold paragraphs in the entire document, i.e. there are 6 bold paragraphs throughout the document, so when I run the macro, it moves the cursor right once then deletes 6 characters. How can I set it to move right once and delete one character after each instance of a bold paragraph? I feel like my problem is with the "For Each" bit, but I don't know what would replace that.

Comment: Your question was how to search for a bold paragraph, so this should really be a separate question. I will try to help though. What character follows each paragraph?

Comment: So basically I extract text from a PDF and output it to a Word doc and run a macro that replaces all paragraph markers with two paragraph markers, to insert a blank line between each paragraph. What I'd like to do it then remove the extra blank line after entirely bold paragraphs (subheadings). I just used the MsgBox bit as my quick and easy way to see if the macro correctly located entirely bold paragraphs only, because it's not always easy to tell otherwise. I just want to delete the paragraph marker following a bold paragraph.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! With a slight amendment to the code, could the same search and paragraph deletion work on selected text, i.e. from a certain point to the end of the document (Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend)?

Comment: Good, please mark the answer as accepted. For the additional item you need to ask a separate question and describe clearly what it is that you are trying to do.